# Filling out Html.DropDownListFor from csv file in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, razor, umbraco

My drop down list is filled out like this at the moment and interacts with my model `employeeModel`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => employeeModel.JobTitle,
            new SelectList(
                 new List<Object>
                 {
                    new { value = "Job Title 1", text = "Job Title 1"},
                    new { value = "Job Title 2", text = "Job Title 2"},
                    new { value = "Job Title 3", text = "Job Title 3"},
                    new { value = "Job Title 4", text = "Job Title 4"}
                },
               "value",
               "text",
               0), "Select...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

However, I need a way to so that I can fill this out way more easily than having to either manually do this by hand. The easiest way I thought of doing this was through a CSV file. However, I have no clue as to how I can get my user to upload the file, then grab all the contents of it so that it can fill the above code snippet.

Has anyone ever done such a thing before?

Answer (score 2):

You could add an Upload field where the user could select a text file containing the list of jobs.  In this case I'm assuming that the file looks something like this:

```
Job Title 1
Job Title 2
Job Title 3
Job Title 4
Job Title 5
```

In your controller you'd have to get the property value and convert it from a relative Uri path to an absolute file path.  Then use StreamReader to read through the file and add the items to a list, before using the values to create a list of SelectListItems and add them to your `employeeModel`.

```
    var fileUri = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<string>("jobFile");
    var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileUri);
    var values = new List<string>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        values = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
    }

    employeeModel.Jobs = values.Select(x =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x,
                Text = x
            };
        });
```

Finally, render the drop down list in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.JobTitle, Model.Jobs, "Select...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```